# MacOS how to automate pressing sequence of key strokes?

Tags: macos, automation

I want to create a script on MacOS that will execute several keystrokes (maybe 5 or 6). 
Is it possible to achieve that without buying comercial software?

I start reading about 'Script Editor' but not sure how to attach whole script to one key stroke?

Comment: AppleScript - have a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript).

Comment: Thanks but do not see there setting a key for script action..

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Use Automator to create a service and assign a shortcut. Google "automator keystroke".